# Net force when deriving relation between torque and angular acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

When deriving the equation $\tau = I\alpha$, it is assumed that $$F_{tangential}=ma_{tangential}$$$$a_{tangential}=\alpha r$$$$\tau=rF_{tangential}$$$$\tau=mr^2\alpha=I\alpha$$

However, doesn’t Newton’s second law describe that $\Sigma F=ma$? And isn’t $\Sigma F$ in this case equal to $F_{centripetal}+F_{tangential}$? Why don’t you have to take into account of centripetal force?

Or you can just arbitrarily throw around $F=ma$ for any force without minding that it’s not the *net* force?

Comment: Look at the derivation under local coordinates. They are dealing with non uniform motion. At the end the net acceleration is the sum of torque and the centripetal force.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force#Alternative_approach

Comment: "_However, doesn’t Newton’s second law describe that $\Sigma F=ma$_". That's true. Similarly, $\sum \tau = I \alpha$.

Comment: In what situation $\tau = m r^2 \alpha$? Because for a uniform solid circular disk it is $\tau = \tfrac{m}{2} r^2 \alpha$ and for a sphere it is $\tau = \tfrac{2 m}{5} r^2 \alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a 2D problem with a 1D problem. In 2D, force and motion also have direction (other than 1 or -1). The two forces you are trying to sum are orthogonal to each other and should not appear in each other's force equilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

To put it in coordinates, let's choose a $(r,\theta)$ coordinate system. In that system $$\vec{F}=F_r\hat{r}+F_{\theta}\hat{\theta}.$$

To calculate the torque about the origin that this force exerts on a particle located at position $\vec{r}$ we calculate a cross product $$\vec{\tau}=\vec{r}\times\vec{F}.$$

In case you don't know about cross products, one of the results is that any component of $\vec{F}$ that is parallel to $\vec{r}$ vanishes, and because $\vec{r}$ points in the $\hat{r}$ direction, the $F_r$ component doesn't contribute to the torque.$$\vec{\tau}=rF_{\theta}\hat{k}$$

For a more intuitive idea, consider this.  If you have a particle at rest some distance from the origin and you exert a force on it directly toward the origin, there is no angular acceleration around the origin. By definition, angular accelerations must be tied to a torque, and vice versa, so zero angular acceleration implies zero torque. Radial forces don't cause torques about the central point.

Answer (score 0):

**$1^{st}$ method**

The torque is only generated by the perpendicular component of force acting along the radius vector (as can be seen from this formula $ \mathbf  \tau = \mathbf r \times \mathbf F $)

---

**$2^{nd}$ method**

You may know that $v \neq \omega r$ but $\mathbf v = \mathbf \omega \times \mathbf r $.
Therefore $\mathbf a = \mathbf \alpha \times \mathbf r $. Now you might notice that since the component of $\mathbf a$ which is parallel to $ \mathbf r$ can never be generated via a cross product therefore the component of acceleration parallel to the radius isn't accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you are thinking about the derivation of the equation properly.  One must take a little care in deriving it from Newton's Laws, but it is fairly straightforward.

It is easy to show, just by taking the cross product $\vec{r} \times \left(\text{Newton II}\right)$, that for a single particle:
$$
\vec{\tau}_{\rm net} = \frac{{\rm d} \vec{\ell}}{{\rm d} t}
$$
where $\vec{\tau}_{\rm net} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}_{\rm net}$ and  $\vec{\ell} := \vec{r} \times \vec{p} = \vec{r} \times m \vec{v}$. And it is not much more difficult to show that the sum of these equations over many particles can be manipulated (at some point applying Newton's Third Law, and also making the assumption that that all internal interaction forces are *central*, i.e., pointing along the line connecting the particles ... which together effect the cancellation of internal torques) into this equation for the system of particles:
$$
\vec{\tau}_{\rm ext} = \frac{ {\rm d} \vec{L}}{{\rm d} t}
$$
where $\vec{L} = \sum \vec{\ell}$, and $\vec{\tau}_{\rm ext}$ is the net external torque on the system.  We might call this result, Newton's Second Law for Rotation of an object.

The equation:
$$
\tau_{{\rm net},z} = I \alpha_z
$$
results from considering the special case of a rigid body (a system of particles where all inter-particle distances are fixed) that rotates about the $z$ axis. In that case: (1) the vector $\vec{r}_i$ from the origin to the $i$th particle can be written as $\vec{r}_i = z_i \hat{k} + \vec{R}_i$ where $\vec{R}_i$ lies in the $x$-$y$ plane; and (2) the path of each particle is a circle of radius $R_i$, with each particle velocity $\vec{v}_i$ lying in the $x$-$y$ plane, always perpendicular to $\vec{R}_i$. Under those conditions, Newton's Second Law for Rotation becomes:
\begin{align}
\vec{\tau}_{\rm ext} &= \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} t} \sum_i \left[ \left(z_i \hat{k} + \vec{R}_i\right) \times m_i \vec{v}_i \right]\\
&= \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} t} \sum_i \left[\left(m_i z_i \, \hat{k} \times \vec{v}_i\right) + \left( m_i R_i v_i \,\hat{k} \right) \right]
\end{align}
where I have assumed that the rotation has $\omega_z>0$ such that $\vec{R}\times\vec{v}$ is in the positive $z$ direction. Because $\hat{k}\times\vec{v}$ is always a vector in the $x$-$y$ plane, if we take the $z$ component of that equation, only the second term in the summand will be nonzero:
$$
\tau_{{\rm ext}, z} = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} t} \sum_i  m_i R_i v_i 
$$
We can further express the speed in terms of the rotational velocity, $\omega_z$, which is the same for all particles, and can therefore be pulled out of the sum. This leads to the natural definition of the moment of inertia, $I$, and to the equation we wish to derive:
\begin{align}
\tau_{{\rm ext}, z} &= \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} t} \sum_i  m_i R_i \left(R_i \omega_z \right)\\
 &= \frac{{\rm d} \omega_z}{{\rm d} t} \sum_i m_i R_i^2\\
 &= I \alpha_z
\end{align}